# Broadcast receiver in contol extension

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sony-smartwatch

I need to know how I can register a Broadcast Receiver on the `ControlExtension` for a SmartWatch app, in order to receive an string from the `PreferenceActivity`
I tried to register it dynamically but I couldn't, the app chrases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to retrieve the preference string normally using something like this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctxt);
String returnedString = preferences.getString("myString", "");
```

Is this what you are looking for, or are you trying to have something fire off when a user changes a preference? You will probably need to make sure the SmartWatch app is running and then you should be able to register a receiver like this:

```
    private void registerBroadcastReceiver() {
        IntentFilter iF = new IntentFilter();
        iF.addAction("com.my.broadcastReceiver");
        ctxt.registerReceiver(mReceiver, iF);           
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() { 
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            String action = intent.getAction();
             if (action == "com.my.broadcastReceiver"); {
               //Perform your actions here
             }
        }
    };
```

Please let me know if this is not what you are looking for. If not tell me more about your problem.

Comment: It was the second one, I needed to start the SW app when user changes a preference so with the second solution, taking care of the SW app was running, I could solve my problem. Tanks